# sed for replacing non-commented lines in file

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sed

I have searched and have found well-informed answers that I think should work, but I can't get them to work. The problem is that I clearly so don't understand sed and all of the slashes and what any of that has to do with regex. I think this is why I can't cross the bridge from very informative answers (such as [sed: -e expression unknown option to `s'](https://serverfault.com/questions/857477/sed-e-expression-unknown-option-to-s)) to making this work for me.

/etc/network/interface:

```
# WAN (Internet connection)
auto wlp3s0 
iface wlp3s0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant_some1.conf
#wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant_oldstuff.conf
```

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NEW_LINE="wp-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant_someother.conf"
sed -i '/wpa-conf /c\'"$NEW_LINE" /etc/network/interfaces
```

The above kind of works. The entire line in the file that begins with wpa-conf is replaced with the new line in the script which is great.

But there is a nasty caveat: the commented wpa-conf line is also changed. This is what I'm trying to avoid. Reading the other answers, I've tried these in the script and a bunch of other hopeless variations that I could think of to no avail. These produce various errors:

```
sed -i '/^#/!s/wpa-conf /c\'"$NEW_LINE" /etc/network/interfaces
sed -i '|^#|!s|wpa-conf /c\'"$NEW_LINE" /etc/network/interfaces
sed -i '|^#|!s|wpa-conf |c\'"$NEW_LINE" /etc/network/interfaces
```

I clearly have no idea what I'm doing and I am evidently unable to understand how sed works and the other answers only made it worse for me.

All I'm trying to do is replace a line with another line as long as it isn't a line that is commented. The replacement line must be given in the form of a variable because it comes from other sources not shown here for brevity.

Regards and Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check out the first answer on [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408182/conditional-replace-using-sed). If you only want make your replacement on lines that begin with 'wpa-conf', you should add `^` and that should do what you want.

`sed -i '/^wpa-conf /c\'"$NEW_LINE" /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Bingo. I got lost in all those slashes from the examples and I couldn't even think properly. Thanks.